# I wante to find some $v>0$ verifying this property

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider a function $f: (0,+∞)→(0,+∞)$. Assuming that $f$ is continuous differentiable and strictly increasing for all $t>0$. 
I want to find some $v>0$ verifying this property:

$$f(a)<f(v)≤c$$

where $a>0$  and $c>0$ are given real numbrers. I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x+2$ for $x>0$. Take $a=0$ and $c=1$. Then $f(a)=f(0)=0 < 1 = c$. But $f(a)<f(v)$ can only happen for $v>0$, in which case $f(v)>2>c$.

Comment: @arts: But $f$ is continuous.

Comment: It wasn't when I wrote it. You added it later as can be seen in the edit history.

Comment: @arts: Yes, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, c > 0$ such that $f(a) < c$ (otherwise it obviously doesn't hold). Then, because $f$ is continuous at $a$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|v - a| < \delta \implies |f(v) - f(a)| \le c - f(a)$.

For any $v \in \langle a, a + \delta\rangle$ we have $f(a) < f(v)$ so:

$$0 < f(v) - f(a) = |f(v) - f(a)| \le c - f(a)$$

Which implies $f(a) < f(v) \le c$.